# play chess with socket.io and uci

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to create a webapp where you can play against a UCI-Chessengine. I found https://github.com/imor/uci which works nice on commandline. So I "only" need a websocket to evaluate the moves.

But I'm not able to get it running... I tried (based on the uci-example):

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('start', function(data) { 
    var uci = new UCI();
    var game = new Chess();
    uci.on('ready', function () {
        //Start a new 10 minute game with engine as black, use the first found
        //engine and the first found polyglot book
        uci.startNewGame(uci.getAvailableEngines()[0], 'black', 10,
            uci.getAvailableBooks()[0]);
    }).on('newgame', function () {
        console.log("A new 10 minute game has started.");
        console.log("Enter your moves in algebraic notation. E.g. e2e4<Enter>");
        console.log(game.ascii());
    }).on('moved', function (move) {
        game.move(move);
        console.log(move.from + move.to + (move.promotion ? move.promotion : ''));
        console.log(game.ascii());
    }).on('error', function (message) {
        console.log('Error:' + message);
    }).on('exit', function (message) {
        console.log('Exiting:' + message);
    }).on('gameends', function (result, reason) {
        console.log('Game ends with result ' + result + ' because ' + reason);
        uci.shutdown();
        process.exit();
    });
  })

  socket.on('m',function(data){
      uci.move(data.move);
  });
});
```

Starting the game is working: socket.emit('start',{"bar":"foo"})
but when I try to make a move with socket.emit('m':"e2e4") it does not know the uci.move

That's okay cause it's defined within socket.on('start')... so he can't know it, but I'm not able to get it running. I've tried some stupid ideas, for example putting the socket.on('m') into the socket.on('start')...

Can somebody help me with this? How can I send moves to the created uci-connection? Or is this not possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: in the code you show I don't think that uci is defined when you try to access its move function. Maybe you should make uci a var that can be accessed by both functions, i.e. moving it up in the scope hierarchy.

Comment: I know, that's what I wrote. But how can I make it available? I'm not very experienced with node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `var uci` up in the scope hierarchy.

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  var uci;
  socket.on('start', function(data) { 
    uci = new UCI();
    var game = new Chess();
    ...
  })

  socket.on('m',function(data){
    uci.move(data.move);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that. It gaves me:
node_modules/uci/lib/main.js:254
    var validMove = self.chess.move(move);
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'move' of undefined

Comment: a wait a minute, I've done the uci=new UCI() outside of the socket.on('start'), when using only var uci outside it seems to work. Let me make some test, thank you until now.

Comment: okay that works, but I if an other client goes to the side he uses the same object. So i need to buid a channel for every game... I try this and came back if I can't get it working

Thank you very much for you quick help.

Comment: you are welcome. scoping can be a tricky issue in javascript.